# How to configure active mq using a load balance domain name?

Tags: sites-9, load-balancing, object-cache, deployerservice, apachemq

I have two content delivery servers in QA environment, where in live and staging services configured based on the load balance(NGNIX domain name e.g.abc.xyz.net)
I was able to bring up all the services,successfully validate publishing to these servers.

I have configured active mq caching which is accessible on machine name e.g. servername:8161/admin.  Referred "tcp://servername:61616?soTimeout=30000" in the remote synchronization node of deployer and content server.  Successfully validate caching invalidation scenarios at deployer and web app level.
Need help on following:

1. how to configure active mq on load balance domain name?
2. Do we need to load balance 61616 port on the servers? is this correct?
3. tcp://servername:61616 - is not accessible out side the server?
   shall i open up firewall on the server to make it accessible ?
4. Can I replace "tcp" with "http" to make it accessible and load balanced? will invalidation works post replacing "tcp" with "http".
   Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to share my knowledge to answer your questions:

Q1: How to configure Active MQ on the load balance domain name?

**A1:**
We could set up a different way of clustering setup for HA.

We did use the broker clustering - [Shared File System Master Slave](https://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave) set up for failover. For this setup Load balance setup not required.

**Broker clusters**:
The most common mental model of clustering in a JMS context is that there is a collection of JMS brokers and a JMS client will connect to one of them; then if the JMS broker goes down, it will auto-reconnect to another broker.

We implement this using the **failover://** protocol in the JMS client. See the [Failover Transport Reference](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference) page for details of how to configure the failover protocol.

This setup needs at least 3 nodes (or some odd number) to avoid issues with [split brain during network partitions](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/network-isolation.html).

It needs shared network storage to persist the messages.

Install the ActiveMQ and configure the **activemq.xml** to a shared directory, ensure all the broker this config points to the same shared directory folder.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

ActiveMQ maintains information about schedules independent to the settings in the persistence adapter. With a shared file-system it is therefore important to tell ActiveMQ expressly where to store scheduler information. To do this, set the dataDirectory attribute on the broker, for example:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
dataDirectory="/some/location"
brokerName="mmuserb2" useJmx="true" advisorySupport="false"
persistent="true" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="false"
useShutdownHook="false" schedulerSupport="true">
```

In the deployer and content services in **cd_storage_conf.xml** for clients should be using the Failover Transport to connect to the available brokers, for example:

```
<RemoteSynchronization>
                <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion">
                    <JndiContext>
                        <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                        <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="failover:(tcp://broker1-ipaddress-or-hostname,tcp://broker2-ipaddress-or-hostname:61616,tcp://broker3-ipaddress-or-hostname:61616)?randomize=false&amp;timeout=5000"/>
                        <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="Tridion-Live"/>
                    </JndiContext>
                </Connector>
</RemoteSynchronization>
```

Q2: Do we need to load balance 61616 port on the servers? is this correct?

**A2:** No and No

Q3: tcp://servername:61616 - is not accessible outside the server? shall I open up a firewall on the server to make it accessible?

**A3:** If you use to invalidate the caching in content-service, then yes ensure deployer and content services servers should have access to ActiveMQ servers on that port 61616.

Q3: Can I replace "tcp" with "http" to make it accessible and load balanced? will invalidation works post replacing "tcp" with "http".

**A3:** No and No

Supported and available different ActiveMQ TransportConnectors:

**openwire:** tcp://0.0.0.0:61616

**amqp:** amqp://0.0.0.0:5672

**stomp:** stomp://0.0.0.0:61613

**mqtt:** mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883

**ws:** ws://0.0.0.0:61614

**Note:**

**Pros:** Run as many slaves as required. Automatic recovery of old masters

**Cons:** Requires shared file system

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I shall try configure and share my observations.

Comment: I configured a shared directory for both load balancers and able to validate the caching scenarios.  It is falling back to slave if master ActiveMq is down.  Thanks for the pointers.