# How to configure ActiveMQ load balancer in two different domains

Tags: load-balancing, activemq

My application is running in two different hardware servers (Linux servers ex: https://application-itg-a1.corp.cloud.net:8161/ and https://application-itg-s2.corp.cloud.net:8161/) with ActiveMQ broker installed in these two hardware servers.

These two hardware servers configured in cluster master-slave architecture

Issue here, how do I configure ActiveMQ load balancer in hardware server(console) level not in broker level?

Comment: Welcome to  Tridion Stack Exchange - Please refer to this link -> https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/how-to-configure-active-mq-using-a-load-balance-domain-name , see if this helps

Comment: are you using on premise or cloud

Comment: Please update if you are still facing the issue with the configuration

Comment: First of all, why do you want to do the console level load balance?